# memoryleak when saving a bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am saving a screenshot of current image on the computer:

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
       g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }

    using (var mss = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(mss,ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

And the memoryleak is at this code:

```
bitmap.Save(mss,ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Shouldn't my use of `using` dispose everything I am using?

Why am I still getting really high memory usage when taking lots of pictures and the memory ain't released back?

Thank you!

Comment: The root question is: why do you need to store a bitmap into a MemoryStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the BufferManager, it will manage Byte[] for you.

```
        // declare the BufferManager somewhere. Check thread safety!
        BufferManager bm = BufferManager.CreateBufferManager(qqq, yyy);


        // wrap your current code to use the buffer manager
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

            byte[] buffer = bm.TakeBuffer(yyy);
            try
            {
              using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
              {
                 bitmap.Save(mss,ImageFormat.Gif);
              }
            }
            finally
            {
               bm.ReturnBuffer(buffer);
            }
       }
```

Comment: Why not just new byte[]? Why BufferManager? It will 1) return buffers of lengths that are either 1M, 2M, 4M, 8M, 16M and so on (and I assume also buffers smaller than 1M, but didn't verify), so if you ask for 9M, you'll get a 16M array. 2) buffer managers will never clean up by themselves, so you have to manually call BufferManager.Clean(). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252417 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265299

Answer (score 3):

You may be seeing the same problem that I encountered when I asked [this question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271891/net-memory-issues-loading-40-images-memory-not-reclaimed-potentially-due-to-l)

The problem in my case was that the `MemoryStream` was not releasing its internal `byte[]` even when calling `Dispose` on it.  The `byte[]` is not freed until the `MemoryStream` goes out of scope and is collected by the GC.

[This blog post](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream.html) details the cause of the problem, and also presents [a working solution.](http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/05/wrappingstream_implementation.html)  It worked for me, and I suspect you are encountering the same problem.  Essentially it wraps the underlying `MemoryStream` in a type that implements the same interface but sets the stream reference to null upon calling `Dispose()`.  As no other objects should have a live reference to the internal stream this allows the GC to swoop in and clean it up.

Also, this issue is compounded by the fact that the internal `byte[]` will likely be allocated on the large object heap, which leads to fragmentation after multiple allocations.

Comment: I am reading it know, did u use the whole class in your situation?

Comment: Yep, I used the whole class.  Not sure how you could get away with any less.  It inherits from the abstract `Stream` class, so you have to implement all of those methods and that's what allows it to be treated as a Stream, even though all of the real work is passed down.

Comment: So i put current memorystream inside the new wrappedstream right?

   using (WrappingStream wp = new WrappingStream(mss))

Gonna try it

Comment: Yep, just like that.  Also, I would suggest using a profiler if you're not already.  The [Redgate ANTS .NET Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) is awesome and they have a 14 day trial (I do not work for them, just like the product :) )

Comment: Are you sure?  At this point you need to run your app through a profiler and come back with the results.  Until you do that we are just guessing.