# Memory not getting released in WPF Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, memory-leaks

I am loading and unloading images in `Canvas`. I used the below code to load the `Image`.

Before loading my `Image` the memory consumption is 14.8MB.

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();

Image im = new Image();
ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"E:Capture.png"));
im.Source = src;
im.Height = 800;
im.Width = 800;

c.Children.Add(im);
homegrid.Children.Add(c); //homegrid is my grid's name
```

The `Image` displayed correctly and the memory consumption now is 20.8MB. Then I unloaded the `Image` by the below code:

```
foreach (UIElement element in homegrid.Children)
{
    if (element is Canvas)
    {
        Canvas page = element as Canvas;

        if (page.Children.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = page.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (page.Children[i] is Image)
                    (page.Children[i] as Image).Source = null;
                page.Children.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        page.Children.Clear();
        page = null;
    }
}

homegrid.Children.RemoveAt(2);
InvalidateVisual();
```

The `Image` gets removed after this, but the memory is still 20.8 MB.

Can anyone help me out this?

Comment: How do you collect garbages?

Comment: That's not a memory leak. The GC will take care of those no more referenced instances eventually.

Comment: @ken2k : I didn't get your point. Can you please elloborate

Answer (score 12):

First of all you should test by explicitly invoking `GC.Collect()` to collect memory and see that memory releases or not because GC collection is indeterministic. You  can't be sure that after your method execution GC runs and reclaim the memory.

So , at end put this code to explicitly force GC to run to check if actually memory is released or not:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

---

However, there is some known memory leak issues in `BitmapImage` creation which you can refer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx), [here](http://haozes.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/wpf-bitmapimage-memory-leak/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271891/net-memory-issues-loading-40-images-memory-not-reclaimed-potentially-due-to).

Actually under the covers WPF keeps a strong reference between the static BitmapImage and the Image and hook some events on Bitmap image. So, you should **freeze the bitmapImage before assigning to image**. WPF doesn't hook events on freezed bitmapImage. Also set CacheOption to avoid any caching memory leak of bitmapImage.

```
Image im = new Image();    
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"E:Capture.png");
bi.EndInit();
bi.Freeze();
ImageSource src = bi;
im.Source = src;
im.Height = 800;
im.Width = 800;
```

Answer (score 1):

In .Net there is something called the **garbage collector** (GC) that is in charge of managing the memory you're using.

- When you create an instance of an object, it requires some more memory.
- When you remove your `ImageSource` from the `Children` collection, you don't actually free any memory, you just say "*I don't want to use this instance anymore*".

At this point the GC will help you. It'll automatically detect instances that are not used anymore, and will free the associated memory for you.

Do note it's an **automatic process** and you shouldn't (and you don't want to) take care of the memory management.

You can call `GC.Collect();` to force the garbage collector to do its job right now, you'll see the memory will be released. **NOTE:** `GC.Collect();` should be used in debug to detect memory leaks, but 99% of times **you shouldn't call it explicitly in production code**. `GC.Collect();` is an operation that can use a lot of CPU time.

Comment: So i use using the image and after my work done i set the imageSource to null and call GC.Collect() .. but memory not going to cleanning.. after some time when i call again GC.Collect() then its clean else its hold memory cheak video:-    https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4ftl9lizqktw31/TinyTake16-08-2018-04-33-11.mp4?dl=0