# How to remove XamlAnimatedGif Image and release its memory occupied?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

**Notice:**

[Memory not getting released in WPF Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877221/memory-not-getting-released-in-wpf-image)
I checked above post, in that post, the Image is associate with a `BitmapImage`. But for my case, I use `XamlAnimatedGif` package. They are different. And I verified his solution doesn't work for my issue.

**Question:**

In my WPF application, I use `XamlAnimatedGit` package to play a gif as loading animation. And after playing, I want to remove it and release its memory occupation.

My code is as below.
When app starts, I will call `ShowLoading()`, and after e.g. 5s, I will call `HideLoading()`.

But if I don't add the loading gif at all, then my application will consume about **40MB** memory. While by adding and playing the loading gif, my application will consume about **100MB** memory, and will not release the memory even after `HideLoading()` is called.

`LoadingBorder.Child = null;` in `HieLoading()`  causes CPU usage dropped from 2.3% to 0.1%, but it doesn't reduce the memory usage.

How to release the memory usage occupied by the gif Image?

xaml code:

```
<Border x:Name="LoadingBorder" Visibility="Hidden" Width="250" Height="250">
    <Image Name="LoadingImageUI" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Border>
```

cs code:

```
    private void HideLoading()
    {
        if (LoadingBorder.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
            return;

        LoadingBorder.Height = 0;
        LoadingBorder.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        LoadingBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        LoadingBorder.Child = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }

    private void ShowLoading()
    {
        LoadingBorder.Height = 250;
        LoadingBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        LoadingUri = new Uri("Asset/pictures/Loading_Dark.gif", UriKind.Relative);
        AnimationBehavior.SetSourceUri(LoadingImageUI, LoadingUri);
    }
```

**Update:**
I add `GC.Collect()` in `HideLoading()`, but the memory still cannot be released.

Comment: @Clemens I tried GC.Collect(), but still cann't release the memory.

Comment: @Clemens Which code? GC.Collect()? I tried it but found that it is useless to release memory, so I delete the line.

Comment: I add it now, please check the main post. @Clemens

Comment: You can't explicitly "release the memory" in a managed app. You can force the garbage collector to collect unreachable objects using the `GC.Collect` method but this doesn't necessarily release the memory back to the operating system immediately.